# How can I use msinfo32 to get system information but only specific info?

Tags: c#

I'm using this code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace System_Information
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetInfo();
        }

        private void GetInfo()
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "msinfo32.exe";
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/report D:\\Info\\report.txt";
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\\Info";
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

but it's creating a very big file size 1.5MB of information.
if I want to use the msinfo32 but to show for example only the memory , video car , and mother board info? How can I select it to show only this info ?

Comment: `... but to show for example only the memory , video car , and mother board info` I am afraid you can't, well at least not the path you're going down.

Comment: Category and Categories switches are not supported anymore, so you cannot ask for a subset. You have WMI Queries, if your app can run elevated.

Comment: @Uniter 3D - [Retrieves a collection of management objects based on a specified query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)